# How to include ```{r} inside RMarkdown without running anything

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to include the following text in my RMarkdown document: ```` ```{r} ````.

However, because this is also the way to start a R code chunk, it will not actually display this text.

How can I get my R Markdown file to display this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the desired output in R Markdown

````
```{r,comment=NA}
cat("```{r}")
````